# iOS 7 set UIImagePickerController leftBarItem

Tags: ios, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller

I have a UIImagePickerController presented as a modal in a UIPopoverController in iOS 7. When it's presented, I don't see any cancel button. I tried to insert a leftBarItem into its navigationBar:

```
picker.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:)];
```

But it doesn't work.

Here is how I presented the picker:

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")) {
    [picker.navigationBar setTranslucent:NO];
    [picker.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlackOpaque];
    [picker.navigationBar setBarTintColor:barGray];        
}else{
    [picker.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:barGray];
}
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:^{
    //I also tried to put the leftBarItem setting code here. Doesn't work either.
}];
```

Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: I bet `navigationItem` is `nil` at that point.

Comment: Actually `navigationItem` is not nil, but `leftBarButtonItem` is able to set, but not the correct viewcontroller apparently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm able to set the `leftBarButtonItem` using the UINavigationController delegate methods. Turns out the `picker.navigationItem` won't cut it because it won't be the root view controller in its own navigation controller